# Set default connection for internet connectivity - ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, routing, redirection

I have two connections on my computer:

sudo route -n

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0`

sudo ifconfig -a

`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet

          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dafe:e3ff:fea8:3849/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:665046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:704568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:353848993 (353.8 MB)  TX bytes:160486634 (160.4 MB)`

`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:70800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11629088 (11.6 MB)  TX bytes:11629088 (11.6 MB)`

`usb0      Link encap:Ethernet

          inet addr:192.168.8.100  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c3e:63ff:fe53:fc9e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15793544 (15.7 MB)  TX bytes:10477325 (10.4 MB)`

ip route show

`default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2  metric 1 
192.168.8.0/24 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.100  metric 1`

Normally, I will be using **Wired connection1** which is wired connection using phone cable. But when I connect the USB device, the problem starts.  New connection will appear as **Wired connection3** and the device is a wifi router with a web interface to login and connect. After I connect the device to USB, every request to any website will be redirected to login page on `192.168.8.1` (which is quite normal). I can load websites for a short while when I manually click **Wired connection1**. But when I continue browsing or refresh the same page, browser will be redirected back to login page of **Wired connection3**(this is not the intended behavior, who choose Wired connection3 again?).

Now to use the Internet, I will have to either disconnect **Wired connection3** (sometimes it appears as **Wired connection4**) from menu or unplug the device.  Is there anyway, I can keep my Internet connection alive on **Wired connection1** and still access the wifi router USB device on **192.168.8.1**?

Update - More clarification

---

```
connection  -  name  -  router access  -  connected router
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wired connection1  -  eth0  -  192.168.1.1  -  beetel router
Wired connection3  -  usb0  -  192.168.8.1  -  usb wireless router with HSPA+
```

**sudo route -n** gives the same output on **Wired connection1** and **Wired connection3** when **Wired connection3** is not disconnected:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0`

when **Wired connection3** disconnects, it changes to:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0`

---

---

Update - After trying @MariusMatutiae's answer

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0`

Still the result switch between login page and actual web-page after choosing **Wired connection1** many times.

Unless I diconnect **Wired connection3**, the results where:

`https://github.com/
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
https://www.digitalocean.com/`

Showing `Unable to connect`

`http://jsonlint.com/`

Showing correct page

`http://superuser.com/
http://askubuntu.com/
http://ionicframework.com/`

Showing `http://192.168.8.1/html/home.html`